# JS String how to extract an array of substring that matches a condition?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, algorithm

I have a string like this:

```
"|hello| + |world| / |again|"
```

And I need to get the substrings inside the `|` and return an array like this:

```
["hello", "world", "again"]
```

What is the best approach to accomplish this?

Comment: probably regex is a good method for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
array = [];
let name = "";
let input = "|hello| + |world| / |again|";
let index = 0;
let isStart = false;

while (index < input.length) {
  if (input[index] == '|') {
    isStart = !isStart;
    if (!isStart) {
      array.push(name);
      name = "";
    }
  } else {
    if (isStart) {
      name = name + input[index];
    }
  }
  index++;
}
console.log(array);
```

Comment: This solution allows whitespaces in between. e.g "|again and again|" -> ["again and again"]

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex that searches for groups consisting only of letters (`([A-Za-z])`) between pipes (`/|`) where the pipes are to omitted from the actual match (wrapped with `(?:)`)-- then use [`.matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) to get all the matches and `.map` the result to get the captured groups only (non-captures omitted) -- see below:

```js
const str = "|hello| + |world| / |again|";

const re = /(?:\|)([A-Za-z]+)(?:\|)/g;

const results = [...str.matchAll(re)].map((entry) => entry[1]);

console.log(results);
```

This will work to match only those words that are between pipes. If you have other words in your string that are *not* wrapped between pipes, they will be ignored. Like the following snippet:

```js
const str = "|hello| + |world| / |again| how are |you| doing?";

const re = /(?:\|)([A-Za-z]+)(?:\|)/g;

const results = [...str.matchAll(re)].map((entry) => entry[1]);

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

If that string doesn't change format use [a regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) against multiple lower-case letters.

```js
const str = '|hello| + |world| / |again|';
const regex = /[a-z]+/g;
console.log(str.match(regex));
```